# HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Email' validating type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou com uma classe `AdministradorDTO` e adicionei alguns validadores nela achei um tutorial na Internet e segui igual porem no meu caso ele dá esse erro no e-mail, antes dava na String também. Mas aí troquei `@NotEmpty` para `@NotNull` e funcionou.

DTO

```
package com.dogwalk.dogwalk.dto;

import com.dogwalk.dogwalk.entity.Administrador;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 *
 * @author andre
 */
public class AdministradorDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    @NotNull(message = "Preencha o campo Nome")
    private String nome;
    @NotNull(message = "Preencha o campo E-Mail")
    @Email(message = "Email inválido")
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    @NotNull(message = "Preencha o campo Adminstrador Master")
    private boolean master;
    private Date dtGravacao;
    private String userGravacao;

    public AdministradorDTO() {
    }

    public AdministradorDTO(Administrador administrador) {
        this.id = administrador.getId();
        this.nome = administrador.getNome();
        this.email = administrador.getEmail();
        this.master = administrador.getMaster();
        this.dtGravacao = administrador.getDtGravacao();
        this.userGravacao = administrador.getUserGravacao();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public void setMaster(boolean master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    public Date getDtGravacao() {
        return dtGravacao;
    }

    public void setDtGravacao(Date dtGravacao) {
        this.dtGravacao = dtGravacao;
    }

    public String getUserGravacao() {
        return userGravacao;
    }

    public void setUserGravacao(String userGravacao) {
        this.userGravacao = userGravacao;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dogwalk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dogwalk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>dogwalk</name>
    <description>Projeto Dog Walk</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Alguém sabe como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 2):

Como você possui o `hibernate-validator` em seu `pom.xml`, altere a anotação de:

`javax.validation.constraints.Email`

Para:

`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email`

Desta forma o Hibernate irá prover o validador adequado que está registrado na aplicação.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado! Mas deu que que a classe Email desse pacote está depreciada!

Comment: Interessante! De fato foi depreciada em favor da JSR380 conforme descrito [aqui](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/), você poderia tentar atualizar sua versão do `validation-api` para versão `2.0.1.Final` e testar voltando o import para `javax.validation.constraints.Email`?

Comment: Atualizei a versão e voltei com o import... Aí o mesmo erro apareceu de novo... Muito estranho...

Comment: Utilize essa do Hibernate por hora, irei verificar mais tarde